# Array based on strings, char list conversions

Tags: c++

I create a multiple table of string type. I keep variables inside (int, string). It gives me an error:

> [Error] cannot convert 'std::string {aka std::basic_string}' to 'char' in assignment

I've created a tree-shaped suite of functions.The program create a multiple array from a file with this format:

```
11 10 2001
CSKA Moscow
12  1
Bayern Munich
...
```

Program:

```
void llegir(std::fstream &_contingut, std::string *_taula) {
  //declaro variables
  int dia, mes, any, puntsLocal, puntsVisitant, i = 0;
  std::string equipLocal, equipVisitant;

  while (!(_contingut.eof())) {
    //llegeixo arxiu
    _contingut >> dia >> mes >> any; //primera linea
    _contingut.ignore();
    getline(_contingut, equipLocal); //segona linea
    _contingut >> puntsLocal >> puntsVisitant; //tercera linea
    _contingut.ignore();
    getline(_contingut, equipVisitant); //quarta linea


    _taula[i][0] = dia;
    _taula[i][1] = mes;
    _taula[i][2] = any;
    _taula[i][3] = equipLocal.c_str();
    _taula[i][4] = puntsLocal;
    _taula[i][5] = equipVisitant.c_str();
    _taula[i][6] = puntsVisitant;

    i++;

  }

}
void creartaulaDelFitxer(std::string _fitxer, std::string *_taula, int &n_taula) {
  std::fstream arxiu;
  arxiu.open(_fitxer, std::fstream:: in );

  if (arxiu.is_open()) {
    std::cout << "existeix";
  } else {
    std::cout << "ERROR OBERTURA FITXER";
  }
  llegir(arxiu, _taula);
}
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  std::string fitxer;
  std::string eurolliga[300][7];
  int n_taula = 0;

  std::cout << "INTRODUEIX NOM FITXER:" << std::endl;
  std::cin >> fitxer;
  creartaulaDelFitxer(fitxer, *eurolliga, int n_taula);
}
```

Comment: Please post complex code in enligsh only. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297673/how-do-i-deal-with-non-english-content

Comment: What line does the error occur on?

Comment: `std::string *_taula` looks fishy. Instead of using raw pointers/arrays you should probably use a container such as `std::vector<string>`. Please [edit] your question and show how you call `creartaulaDelFitxer` including the declaration of the involved variables. You should also show where __exactly__ the error occurs.

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing pointers, chars and strings which will certainly cause a lot of headache. Try to use the standard containers, like `std::string` and `std::vector`. If you need many strings, put them in a vector. When you have a collection of data like

```
11 10 2001
CSKA Moscow
12  1
Bayern Munich
```

that describes some entity, create a `class` for it. You can then add streaming operators for that class to read in one of these entities. If you have a collection of entities, make a container and add streaming operators for that too.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

class Game {
    std::string equipLocal{};
    std::string equipVisitant{};
    int dia{}, mes{}, any{};
    int puntsLocal{}, puntsVisitant{};

public:
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream&, Game&);
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Game&);
};

// read one entity from an istream
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, Game& g) {
    if(is >> g.dia >> g.mes >> g.any) {
        is.ignore();
        if(std::getline(is, g.equipLocal) && (is >> g.puntsLocal >> g.puntsVisitant)) {
            is.ignore();
            std::getline(is, g.equipVisitant);
        }
    }
    return is;
}

// write one entity to an ostream
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Game& g) {
    return os << g.dia << " " << g.mes << " " << g.any << "\n"
              << g.equipLocal << "\n"
              << g.puntsLocal << " " << g.puntsVisitant << "\n"
              << g.equipVisitant << "\n";
}

class EuroLiga {
    std::vector<Game> games{};

public:
    bool Load(const std::string& filename) {
        std::ifstream arxiu(filename);
        if(arxiu) {
            games.clear();
            arxiu >> *this; // use this class' friend, operator>>
            return true;
        } else
            return false;
    }

    // support for basic non-const iteration over the 'games'
    std::vector<Game>::iterator begin() { return games.begin(); }
    std::vector<Game>::iterator end() { return games.end(); }

    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream&, EuroLiga&);
};

// read all entities from an istream
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, EuroLiga& el) {
    Game tmp;
    while(is >> tmp) {
        el.games.push_back(std::move(tmp));
    }
    return is;
}

int main() {
    EuroLiga euroliga;
    std::string fitxer;

    std::cout << "INTRODUEIX NOM FITXER: ";
    std::cin >> fitxer;
    euroliga.Load(fitxer);

    // display all entities read from the file
    for(auto& g : euroliga) {
        std::cout << g << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: looks good. would've done the same thing, and more expansive than my answer. even more impressive that you figured out he was talking about some game or other.

Comment: Thanks :-) It was EuroLiga and the team names that got me thinking in that direction.

Answer (score 0):

`void llegir(std::fstream &_contingut, std::string *_taula)`

Gets a pointer to a string called _taula, this is probably your array.
However you assign something to your array like this:

```
_taula[i][0] = dia; // allowed, but bad because char is basically a number.
[...]
_taula[i][3] = equipLocal.c_str(); // not allowed, you are assigning a char pointer to a char.
```

taula[i] is the i-th string in your array. And by putting `[0]` you assign to the first character in that string. dia is an integer though.

For example

```
std::string[] = {"Hello", "world", "I", "am", "alive"};
std::cout << string[1] << std::endl; // output "world"
std::cout << string[1][0] << std::endl; // output 'w'
```

You can not assign a string to a single character.

As a side note, you should look into declaring an enumeration for your array index (and a constant for it's size) to make it more clear and improve maintainability.

What you should probably be doing is create a struct or class for your, whatever it is

```
struct whateverItIs {
    int dia, mes, any, puntsLocal, puntsVisitant;
    std::string equipLocal, equipVisitant;
};
```

Make a `new` instance of that in your `llegir` and push it to the back of a `std::vector` you get by reference.
Just remember to `delete()` them later especially before that vector goes out of scope.

Comment: Since `dia` is an integer and not a `std::string`, I suspect the error is somewhere else, maybe even in code not shown in the question.